# Servlet request.getParameter() not working as expected

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, parameters

I've got following code inside a servlet. I don't know why, but for some reason,
Whatever I try, the sysout prints null. WHen I print out usersGuess it works just fine.

```
String usersGuess=request.getParameter("aNumber");

Random r= new Random();
int computerGenerated = r.nextInt(5);

String resultMessage="You guessed "+usersGuess+" the number was "+computerGenerated;        
request.setAttribute("result", resultMessage);
System.out.println(request.getParameter("result"));
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is?

Comment: You are setting *attribute* but you are printing *parameter*.

Answer (score 2):

Try reading the attribute rather than the parameter

```
System.out.println(request.getAttribute("result"));
```